# WinUI3 DataGrid columns with x:Bind

Tags: xaml, mvvm, binding, datagrid, winui-3

Is there an MVVM way (using a ViewModel) to use **x:bind** in XAML for DataGrid columns (DataGridTextColumn, etc)?

All the code I've seen uses Binding not x:Bind.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, unfortunately no. The DataGrid doesn't support `x:Bind`. There was a [feature request](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/issues/2112) a long time ago but I don't think it's going to be supported anytime soon.